# When i use ado.net model in 3-tier architecture and i tries to load the data from DAL to UI it asks for connection string in UI app.config

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, ado.net, 3-tier

Problem with connectiong string in 3-tier architecture using ADO.NET model.
When I try to load data from database using ADO.NET context it asks for connection string when it has already added in DAL app.config but it asks for it in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string must be on the `.config` file on the project which will execute, for sample, windows forms, web application, wpf, wcf, web api, mobile projects. If add a connection string on a app.config file on a class library project, it will not affect your project. You have to keep it on the project which will execute the solution.